# How to handle device with unknown minor number?

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

i have a task: create a simple character device with major number = 255 and print "Hello World" every time when it is being opened. It's really simple task, but i don't know, how to handle device with unknown minor number. I can create an array of 256 elements of my device structure and bind it with (255, i) node number. But it can`t be optimal, because there is 255 unused objects of structures in memory. So, how can i handle a device with known major and unknown minor number?

```
#include <linux/init.h>
#include <linux/module.h>
#include <linux/cdev.h>
#include <linux/fs.h>
#include <linux/slab.h>

MODULE_LICENSE("GPL");

static struct _device
{
    size_t openCount, totalDataWritten;
    struct cdev c_dev;
    dev_t deviceNumber;
};


static struct _device *myDevice;

static int devOpen(struct inode * n, struct file * f)
{
    myDevice->openCount++;          
    return 0;
}

static ssize_t devWrite(struct file * n, char const __user * c, size_t size, loff_t *l)
{
    myDevice->totalDataWritten += size;
    return size;
}

static ssize_t devRead(struct file *fp, char __user *buf, size_t size, loff_t *off)
{
    char *tmpbuf = (char*) kmalloc(size, GFP_KERNEL);
    sprintf(tmpbuf,"%i %i\n", myDevice->openCount, myDevice->totalDataWritten);
    return size - copy_to_user(buf, tmpbuf, size);
}

static struct file_operations devOPS = 
{
    .owner = THIS_MODULE,
    .open = devOpen,
    .write = devWrite,
    .read = devRead,        
}; 

static const int major = 255, minor = 0;
static dev_t devID;
static const char *name = "solution_node";

static int __init deviceInit(void)
{
    myDevice = (struct _device *) kmalloc(sizeof(struct _device), GFP_KERNEL);
    devID = MKDEV(major, minor);

    if (register_chrdev_region(devID, 1, name) != 0)
    {
        return -1;
    }

    cdev_init(&myDevice->c_dev, &devOPS);
    myDevice->c_dev.owner = THIS_MODULE;
    myDevice->c_dev.ops = &devOPS;
    myDevice->openCount = 0;
    myDevice->totalDataWritten = 0;
    myDevice->deviceNumber = MKDEV(major, minor + 1);

    if (cdev_add(&myDevice->c_dev, myDevice->deviceNumber, 1))
    {
        return -2;
    }   
        
    return 0;
}

static void __exit deviceExit(void)
{
    cdev_del(&myDevice->c_dev);
    unregister_chrdev_region(devID, 1);
    return;
}

module_init(deviceInit);
module_exit(deviceExit);
```

Comment: Show us the code you have so far, otherwise it's hard to help you. Where is exactly the problem? When you create a device in the appropriate way, you can ask for a minor number to be automatically assigned, and the kernel will give you one (this is also true for the major number by the way).

Comment: *"how can i handle a device with known major and unknown minor"* - handle what? Creating it in kernel space? Finding the device from userspace? Creating a node in `/dev`?  Be more specific.

Comment: @MarcoBonelli, i meant "how to create it in kernel space". Code has been added, thanks!

Comment: @MarcoBonelli, There is already created node by mknod. I know only major number. The problem is "How to work with a device without known minor number"?

Comment: In all character device callbacks you will get a minor on which an event happened. Read documentation, please.

Comment: `myDevice->deviceNumber = MKDEV(major, minor + 1);` looks wrong. It is outside the registered chrdev region. Perhaps you meant `myDevice->deviceNumber = MKDEV(major, minor);`?

Comment: You shouldn't be using major number 255 because it is reserved.

Comment: @0andriy, which events do you mean? Open, write, read events can be called only for registered in cdev by node number device.

Comment: @IanAbbott, it's the task for automatic tested system, i can`t ignore this.

Comment: There is a memory leak in `devRead()`.

Comment: `sprintf(tmpbuf,"%i %i\n", myDevice->openCount, myDevice->totalDataWritten);` is a potential buffer overflow. Use `snprintf`. Also `%i` is the wrong format specifier.

Comment: @IanAbbott, yes, there is no kfree yet, because i'm focused on described problem.

Comment: @IanAbbott, can you elaborate what's wrong with `%i`? Ah, the parameters seem to be of `size_t` type, hence `%zu` is the correct one.

Comment: @0andriy, @ianAbbott, sorry, guys, looks like i didn`t understand cdev_add() function.

Comment: `register_chrdev_region(devID, 256, name)` and `cdev_add(&myDevice->c_dev, myDevice->deviceNumber, 256);` wouldn't have much (if any) additional overhead compared to registering a single device number.